# Error when trying to start Webrick on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, webrick

this is the output I get when using the 'rails server'

the page does also not load when trying to access it through Google Chrome, this is on a virtual machine

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.7 application starting in development on http: //0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/ubuntu/tracks/tmp (Errno::EACCES)
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `fu_mkdir'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `block in mkdir_p'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `mkdir_p'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:125:in `block in create_tmp_directories'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in `each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in `create_tmp_directories'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:66:in `start'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:10:in `require'
        from bin/rails:10:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The user you're using to start webrick does not have rights to create a directory under the `/home/ubuntu/tracks` folder.

Make sure you are either `ubuntu` or a user that has the same rights as `ubuntu`.

You can also simply do:

```
sudo su
su ubuntu
```

And your shell will be `ubuntu`.